# Android c++ string support for to_string, stof, etc

Tags: android, c++, string, android-ndk, std

Does any android ndk compiler, based on `gcc 4.7`, support `to_string`, `stof`, and other string conversion functions?

In the NDK I am using I found the function in `ext/vstring.h`. But the function is wrapped in

```
#if (defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99))
```

I am enabling `-std=c++11` flag.

How do I enable `GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X`?

Answer (score 0):

I've enabled it by just adding it as a symbol in Project properties->C/C++ General->Symbols->GNU C++

I also added this in Android.mk:
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x